# ArUco marker coordinates in the image plane

Tags: c++, opencv, marker, aruco

Using OpenCV v3.1, I detect an ArUco marker, and with

`aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, camMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs,tvecs);`

I can get the rotation and translation vector for said marker from the marker coordinate system to the camera coordinate system.

However, I need just the xy-coordinates of the marker in the image plane (in pixels). How would I go about this?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363618/aruco-markers-with-opencv-get-the-3d-corner-coordinates) somewhat relevant, but that's, again, in regards to the camera coordinate system.

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html
Looks like you need cv::aruco::detectMarkers

Answer (score 1):

Python:
Get pixel coordinates within the image from detected ArUco Marker, you can use this code as follows:

```
detector = cv.aruco.ArucoDetector(aruco_dict, detetc_params)

for (marker, id) in zip(corners, ids): 
    corner = marker.reshape((4, 2))
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = corner
    cx = (tl[0] + br[0]) / 2
    cy = (tl[1] + br[1]) / 2

print(cx, cy, "cx /cy")

cv.circle(frame, (int(cx), int(cy)), 4, (255, 255, 1), 2) # Using this to draw a circle on the frame of the center point.
```

Comment: Although this may be helpful, it is generally recommended to post answers in the language(s) with which the question is tagged. In this case, Python is not one of those languages.