# Aruco Marker World Coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, aruco

I've been working with Python's OpenCV library, using ArUco for object tracking.

The goal is to get the x/y/z coordinates at the center of the ArUco marker, and the angle in relation to the calibrated camera.

I am able to display axes on the aruco marker with the code I have so far, but cannot find how to get x/y/z coordinates from the rotation and translation vectors (if that's even the right way to go about it).

This is the line of code which defines the rotation/translation vectors:

```
rvec, tvec, _ = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs) # For a single marker
```

Any ideas on how to get angle/marker position in the camera world?

Thanks!

Comment: tvec itself is the x/y/z coordinates of the marker in the coordinate system of the camera, and rvec is the rotation of the marker with respect to the camera (you could convert it to a 3x3 rotation matrix using Rodrigues()). Is this different to the result you are expecting?  You said the axes you draw line up correctly with the captured image, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some tribulation, I found that the x and y coordinates in aruco can be determined by the average of the corners:

```
x = (corners[i-1][0][0][0] + corners[i-1][0][1][0] + corners[i-1][0][2][0] + corners[i-1][0][3][0]) / 4
y = (corners[i-1][0][0][1] + corners[i-1][0][1][1] + corners[i-1][0][2][1] + corners[i-1][0][3][1]) / 4
```

And the angle relative to the camera can be determined by the Rodrigues of the rotation vector, the matrix must be filled prior

```
rotM = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
cv2.Rodrigues(rvec[i-1], rotM, jacobian = 0)
```

Finally, yaw pitch and roll can be obtained by taking the RQ Decompose of the rotation matrix

```
ypr = cv2.RQDecomp3x3(rotM)
```

Answer (score 2):

As said by chungzuwalla, tvec represents the position of marker center in camera coordinate system and it doesn't change with the rotation of marker at a position. If you want to know about location of corners in camera coordinate system then one needs both rvec and tvec.

Here is a perfect explanation

[Aruco markers with openCv, get the 3d corner coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363618/aruco-markers-with-opencv-get-the-3d-corner-coordinates?rq=1)