# Where is the Aruco marker {0,0,0}?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, aruco

When drawing the detected marker on screen , I see there is small rectangle on top left corner and the Axis are drawn in the center of the marker.

When I get translation of the Aruco marker , are they related to the center of the marker or to the top left corner ?

I've searched in the documentation and didn't find reference to where in the marker are the distances referring to....

Comment: for a single marker, it's the center, where the axes are drawn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , Where in the documentation is it written ?

Comment: I can’t recall a documentation for that, but you can look it up in their code (available on GitHub).

Comment: here is the perfect explanation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363618/aruco-markers-with-opencv-get-the-3d-corner-coordinates?rq=1