# Yaw angle from aruco are very noised for right angle

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, orientation, aruco

Recently, I was working with navigation system based on aruco, I need the most accurate possible value of Z axis from aruco marker.

I was built simple measuring system with few aruco marker (type cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_50) and usb web camera 640x480.
I made calibrate for this camera with chessboard and standard opencv method.

I know that if I want to get camera pose data, I must rotate rvec and tvec data from`cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers` and I realized this by this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58112142.

Now we come to the heart of the problem, if I hold the camera at a relatively sharp angle let's say ~ 20 degrees or more (in the yaw angle) algorithm results are probably correct and consistent. If I approach the right angle of the camera in relation to the marker, I notice that the indications start to be much noisy (for a right angle the values oscillate between 0-10 degrees for the yaw angle).

What could it be caused by? Wrong method of transformation, or maybe the aruco tags have such a defect?

Greetings

Comment: mathematical inevitability. -- [mre] is required. please take the [tour]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).